# What does Relevance mean exactly as a sort option for a search? What's the criteria behind it?

Tags: discussion, support, search

What does Relevance mean exactly as a sort option for a search? What's the criteria behind it? It's an obscure unclear word. I did a search in the help center for it and got zero results back! Is it the number of times my keywords exist in the question? Across the answers as well? ...what?

Comment: It means "how much each result is relevant to the search term", i.e. using a "weight" for each result to sort them.

Comment: The help center should bring results back regarding the word Relevance. The link you mentioned says 'The strength of the search match'. It's still an unclear definition. It needs more clarity.

Comment: Not really. It's internal mechanism, not a common term.

Comment: Everything in a UI should be clear to the average user without an ambiguity. Not everyone is an expert in computer search or Lucene. There are non technical StackExchange websites out there with non technical users and I bet they have no idea what relevance means. Relevant in what way...

You said it yourself. It's not a common term which means some people have no idea what it means or what they expect from it.